# How to change point color in Deneb while having lines be the same color as the legend

Tags: powerbi, deneb

I have the following code in Deneb Vega Lite. It produces a scatter plot that has a connected mean line between each group. I am trying to change the color of the points to all be light grey and the lines to be the same color as the legend. Currently it seems that the legend color replaces whatever I put in the point section

[image]

```html
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "point", "opacity": 0.3},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Movie", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "Rating", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "point": {"filled": true}},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Movie", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "mean", "field": "Rating"},
        "detail": {"field": "Country", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "Country",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {"title": "Country"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't see your legend. Add a sample .pbix link so we can use the same data.